# Parent term relations select list as Hierarchical select list

Tags: theming, taxonomy-terms, entities

I would like to change the Taxonomy relation select list like as Hierarchical Select list, how can I change its nature?

Please help[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OfoYE.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check "Hierarchical Select Taxonomy" sub-module in [Hierarchical Select](https://www.drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select) module. After installing "Hierarchical Select Taxonomy" module it will automatically convert normal select list into hierarchical select list. Please check screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks many its working well. One more help! How do I make this as Single Select list box, since it is now with multiple select options. Any code snippet are available for this?

Comment: Hierarchical select box works with multiple dropdown, u might need to do it custom if need in single dropdown